# How to create a crp code for sin function

Tags: python, nonlinear-functions

I want to find the cross recurrence plot for the sin(x) function, with a time delay t that I will input. I do not know the specific functions that will get me to the image I want; it is essentially Sin(x) vs Sin(x)+tau

Expecting something like this

Comment: Your image or example is missing "Expecting something like this"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.